# How to make derived variable in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have two stores:

```
export const custom_items = writable([]);
export const another_items = writable([]);
```

Both of them have array of objects, the object looks like this (of course, values are different):

```
{
    id: 123
    amount: 123
    price: 123
}
```

I would like to make my own derived variable which will hold total amount of the both stores "custom_items" and "another_items". How can i do that?

I can do it only by this code but it is not reactive:

```
function get_total_amount() {
    let total = 0;
    get(custom_items).every((item) => {
        total += item.amount;
    })
    get(another_items).every((item) => {
        total += item.amount;
    })
    return total;
}
```

There must be a better way, i've heard about derived stores but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [derived store](https://svelte.dev/docs#derived):

```js
export const custom_items = writable([]);
export const another_items = writable([]);

const get_total = items => items.flat().map(x => x.amount).reduce((t, x) => t + x, 0)
    
export const total = derived(
  [custom_items, another_items], // deps
  items => get_total(items)      // [...values] => derived_value
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up some local variables/functions, like:

```
<script>

let total_one = 0;

let total_two = 0;

$: total_store_one = get(custom_items).every((item) => {
        total_one += item.amount;
    })
$: total_store_two = get(another_items).every((item) => {
        total_two += item.amount;
    })
$: total = total_store_one + total_store_two;
</script>
```

and use those variables in your code like:

```
<p>Total from store one: {total_store_one}</p>
<p>Total from store two: {total_store_two}</p>
<p>Total: {total}</p>
```